# Regex to remove last letter of each word in list

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I list that I have created in coldfusion. Lets use the following list as an example:

```
<cfset arguments.tags = "battlefieldx, testx, wonderful, ererex">
```

What I would like to do is remove the "x" from the words that have an x at the end and keep the words in the list. Order doesn't matter. A regex would be fine or looping with coldfusion would be okay too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex to grab the `'x'` from the end of a word is pretty straightforward. Supposing you have a given element as a string, the regex you need is simply:

```
REReplace(myString, "x$", "")
```

This matches an x at the end of the given string and replaces it with an empty string.

To do this for each substring in a comma-delimited list, try:

```
REReplace(myString, "x,|x$", ",", "ALL")
```

Comment: Your second expression will append a `,` to the end of the list - using a lookahead (i.e. `x(?=,|$)`) avoids this, by looking for but not including the comma in the match (and thus not requiring it on the replacement side, so it doesn't get added to the end).

Comment: @PeterBoughton You're entirely correct - yours is the better answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Removing `x` from end of each list element...**

To remove all `x` characters that preceed a comma or the end of string, do:

```
rereplace( arguments.tags , "x(?=,|$)" , "" , "all" )
```

The `(?=  )` part here is a lookahead - it matches the position of its contents, but does not include them in what is replaced. The `|` is alternation - it'll try to match a literal `,` and if that fails it'll try to match the end of the string (`$`).

**If you don't want to remove a lone x from, e.g. "x,marks,the,spot"...**

If you want to make sure that x is at the end of a word (i.e. is not alone), you can use a non-word boundary check:

```
rereplace( arguments.tags , "\Bx(?=,|$)" , "" , "all" )
```

The `\B` will not match if there isn't a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` before the `x` - for more complex/accurate rules on what constitutes "end of a word", you would need a lookbehind, which can't be done with rereplace, but is still easy enough by doing:

```
arguments.tags.replaceAll("(?<=\S)x(?=,|$)" , "" )
```

(That looks for a single non-whitespace character before the x to consider it part of a word, but you can put any limited-width expression within the lookbehind.)

Obviously, to do any letter, switch the `x` with `[a-zA-Z]` or whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
REReplace(myString, "x$", "")
```

The `$` symbol is going to be used to detect the end of the string. Thus detecting an `'x'` at the end of your string. The empty quotes will replace it with nothing, thus removing the `'x'`.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered, but thought I'd post a ColdFusion only solution since you said you could use either. (The RegEx is obviously much easier, but this will work too)

```
<cfset arguments.tags = "battlefieldx, testx, wonderful, ererex">
<cfset temparray = []>

<cfloop list="#arguments.tags#" index="i">
  <cfif right(i,1) EQ 'X'>
    <cfset arrayappend(temparray,left(i,len(i) - 1))>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset arrayappend(temparray,i)>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfset arguments.tags = arraytolist(temparray)>
```

If you have ColdFusion 9+ or Railo you can simplify the loop using a ternary operator

```
<cfloop list="#arguments.tags#" index="i">
  <cfset cfif right(i,1) EQ 'X' ? arrayappend(temparray,left(i,len(i) - 1)) : arrayappend(temparray,i)>
</cfloop>
```

You could also convert `arguments.tags` to an array and loop that way

```
<cfloop array="#listtoarray(arguments.tags)#" index="i">
  <cfset cfif right(i,1) EQ 'X' ? arrayappend(temparray,left(i,len(i) - 1)) : arrayappend(temparray,i)>
</cfloop>
```